# Sum function issue with Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

This works for my multiply function but when I try it with a simple +=, it produces the array values in sequence vs. adding them?

```js
//sum()
function sum() {
    var val1 = document.getElementById('sumMulti').value;
    var array = val1.split(',');
    
    var arraySum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        arraySum += array[i];
        
    }
    document.getElementById('displayLabel').innerHTML = "The sum of your numbers is: " + arraySum.toString() + ".";
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">  
  <label class="control-label">Enter Numbers Seperated by ",":</label>
  <br />
  <input type="text" id="sumMulti" class=" form-control" />            
  <button type="submit" onclick="sum()" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="margin:20px 60px 10px 0px;">Sum()</button>
  
  <div id="displayLabel" class="control-label"></div>
    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to learn to love the `parseInt` function.

The default radix is 10, but you can specify other bases as well (for example, sometimes it's handy to parse hexadecimal with `parseInt(hexString, 16)`).

If you expect real numbers, you may prefer `parseFloat` instead. It takes the same parameters.

As to why this worked for multiplication, Javascript is notorious for doing type conversions behind your back. Strings have a `+` operator (concatenate), so when you get the value of an input (which is a string before parsing) it will perform concatenation. However, strings *do not* have a `*` operator. Behind your back, the Javascript runtime attempts to parse the strings as decimal numbers and then multiply. This is not behavior I would count on, so I'd prefer to explicitly parse all inputs first and then perform arithmetic operations on them.

```js
//sum()
function sum() {
    var val1 = document.getElementById('sumMulti').value;
    var array = val1.split(',');
    
    var arraySum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        arraySum += parseInt(array[i], 10);
        
    }
    document.getElementById('displayLabel').innerHTML = "The sum of your numbers is: " + arraySum.toString() + ".";
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">  
  <label class="control-label">Enter Numbers Seperated by ",":</label>
  <br />
  <input type="text" id="sumMulti" class=" form-control" />            
  <button type="submit" onclick="sum()" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="margin:20px 60px 10px 0px;">Sum()</button>
  
  <div id="displayLabel" class="control-label"></div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, Austin!  Can you explain why the multiply function worked without the parseInt function?

Comment: Updated answer with explanation.

Comment: Outstanding, thank you! I would up vote your response but I'm new to SO so it won't let me :(

Comment: Try opening a console (F12 in IE, ctrl-shift-j in Chrome, I'm not sure about the others) and doing `"5" + "5"` and `"5" * "5"` to see JS messing with you. Then try "letters" * "are not numbers".

Comment: You can always accept the answer if it works for you :-)

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse the numbers into integers.

```js
//sum()
function sum() {
    var val1 = document.getElementById('sumMulti').value;
    var array = val1.split(',');
    
    var arraySum = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        arraySum += parseInt( array[i] );
        
    }
    document.getElementById('displayLabel').innerHTML = "The sum of your numbers is: " + arraySum.toString() + ".";
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">  
  <label class="control-label">Enter Numbers Seperated by ",":</label>
  <br />
  <input type="text" id="sumMulti" class=" form-control" />            
  <button type="submit" onclick="sum()" class="btn btn-primary pull-right" style="margin:20px 60px 10px 0px;">Sum()</button>
  
  <div id="displayLabel" class="control-label"></div>
    
</div>
```

Comment: `parseFloat` may work better in case there are non-integers in the input.